# Find basis given a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a linear map in the standard basis $\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$ I need to find a basis $B$ such that the transformation is given by the diagonal matrix $\mbox{diag} \{ 1, -4, 6 \}$ with respect to that basis.

I'm supposed to do it without first computing a matrix that will take me from standard basis to $B$, because that follows in the next question. How do I just find a new basis in which the transformation is defined without finding how to get to that basis?

Comment: do you know about eigen-values and eigen-vectors?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $1$, $-4$, and $6$ are (necessarily) the eigenvalues of your matrix.  And you want to find basis vectors $b_1,b_2,b_3$ such that $Ab_1=1\cdot b_1$, $Ab_2=-4b_2$, and $Ab_3=6b_3$.

It should be clear how to find vectors that satisfy this last property; then, just show that the vectors you choose *happen* to be a basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is the process of diagonalizing the matrix.

This is possible if you find three linearly independent eigenvectors to use as columns on the right of your matrix.

Call your matrix above A, and make a three by three matrix X whose columns are those three eigenvectors. Then $AX=XD$ 
where D is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Shuffle the columns of X to get the right order on the diagonal. (Leaving that as an exercise for you: it's very obvious how to get the right order)

At this point you have that $A=XDX^{-1}$. The basis you seek will appear as images of the old basis under X or under $X^{-1}$. I'm leaving it up to you to determine which!